# Expand View On dragging

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, view, frame

Unfortunately I couldn't find anything about my problem on stackoverflow or maybe I just used the wrong keywords.

I want to have a view which can be moved and increased or decreased by the user. See the image as a reference. There are 4 anchor points with which the user is able to define the frame of the rectangle.

[image: reference]

Can you help finding a easy way how to achieve this?

Thanks so much and best regards from Germany,
Chris

Comment: do you need something like scaling? like if you touch and scale your view the frame of it should change accordingly?

Comment: here u can get https://www.cocoacontrols.com/tags/uiimage have a idea on this

Comment: @ChristianPappenberger it is just like a buzz words that u need to search with google that's it ....

Comment: @ChristianPappenberger : hey buddy please accept my post as an answer of your question if it helped to short-out your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this i've using it for imageview but you can change it for UIView and make sure that userInterAction is True for that view
declare it in .h file

```
CGFloat lastScale;
```

in viewDidLoad:

```
UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchRecognizer = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(scale:)];
[pinchRecognizer setDelegate:self];
[imgRotate addGestureRecognizer:pinchRecognizer];


-(void)scale:(id)sender
{
if([(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
{
    lastScale = 1.0;
    return;
}

CGFloat scale = 1.0 - (lastScale - [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender scale]);

CGAffineTransform currentTransform = [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender view].transform;
CGAffineTransform newTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(currentTransform, scale, scale);

[[(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender view] setTransform:newTransform];

[imgRotate setTransform:newTransform];
lastScale = [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender scale];
}
```